# EffectiveUsername in connection string: "The user name or password is incorrect"

Tags: ssas

I'm trying to use that EffectiveUserName method to test SSAS cube security.  I'm sure I got this to work about a year ago, but it's one of those infuriating things that you finally get to work, and then forget about because getting to that point was so horrible.

The basic idea I'm familiar with (outlined [here](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2012/10/7/unit-testing-role-security-in-analysis-services.html) for example).  You connect to SSAS using your own login, but pretending to the cube that you're another user.

In SSMS Cube Browser, I can use the (new) excellent "connect as role" dialog to test this.  In Excel or SSMS, there isn't this option, so I have to try to use the EffectiveUserName parameter.  But I get an error every time.

- I am an SSAS Server Administrator, and it's my own Windows login on the main connection string page
- The users I'm trying to impersonate exist in SSAS roles, and can browse the cube.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "it's my own Windows login on the main connection string page" meaning you typed in your username and password or that you checked "Integrated Security"?

Comment: In the Connect to Server box (SSMS), Authentication is set to "Windows Auth", User name is set to my login, and Password is blank.  All these are disabled, presumably because it's an SSAS connection and there's no point offering the option of SQL Server logins.  This works in normal usage.  It's only when I set EffectiveUserName="DOMAIN\AnotherUserName" in the Additional Conn Params section that I get the error.

Comment: @SebTHU Hi! Did you find a solution to the problem? I have the same after migration to 2017 SQL Server =(

Comment: @Nick: sadly, no, I just worked around it.